# How to build a project written in Rust using the old Rust compiler?

Tags: rust, build, rust-cargo

I have a project written in Rust.

It was compiled without problems using the Rust compiler version "1.64.0".

At some point I decided to do:

> cargo update

As a result, the "Cargo.lock" file was updated and now I can't build the project:

> error: package `regex-syntax v0.8.2` cannot be built because it
>
> requires rustc 1.65 or newer... ... error: package `home v0.5.9`
>
> cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.70.0 or newer...

I haven't saved the previous version of the "Cargo.lock" file.

Also I don't want (cannot) update my Rust compiler.

Is it possible to:

- recover the possibility to build my project using old Rust "1.64.0"?
- generate a "Cargo.lock" file for a specific version of the Rust compiler?

If yes, then how?

Comment: Use git to revert your Cargo.toml to get the previous versions back

Comment: Either revert in git to previous version (if you don't use git, then you should), or just manually downgrade your dependencies.

Comment: But you should really consider upgrading your toolchain. `1.64.0` was released over 1.5 year ago. This is considered pretty old in this Rust land and you won't be able to use new versions of many libraries.

Comment: Let me clarify. I'm trying to find a general solution and find out if the Rust infrastructure is mature enough in this regard. I cannot update the toolchain, because it was provided to me by a third-party developer (with custom OS support).

Comment: "I cannot update the toolchain, because it was provided to me by a third-party developer" **no** infrastructure is *that* mature. There are *always* new CVEs being discovered and versions of the compiler/libraries get patched accordingly. If you didn't set up a support contract with this developer then you will need to dive in yourself and figure out what the upgrade blockers are if not now then sometime in the not-too-distant future. That being said, the comment from vallentin absolutely solves your immediate problem.

Comment: You can find out the latest version of each crate that supports Rust 1.64.0 from the "versions" tab on crates.io (e.g. for [`regex-syntax`](https://crates.io/crates/regex-syntax/versions) you need version [0.7.5](https://crates.io/crates/regex-syntax/0.7.5)). Then edit your `Cargo.toml` to add the right version requirements (e.g. `regex-syntax = "<0.8"`).

Comment: @Jmb Thanks for this tip. However, this method is not suitable for large applications with many dependencies :(

Comment: Large applications with many dependencies should check in their `Cargo.lock` in their VCS, so they can just revert the change when a `cargo update` brings in an incompatible crate. If you didn't, you'll need to fix it by hand.

Comment: The kind of programs and organizations that stick to a certain language version and only update it once a while tends to also be the kind that minimize their usage of third-party dependencies.